# I have two home page in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have two home pages in magento 2. One `abc.com` and another `abc.com/index.php`

- How can I get rid of this duplication?
- How can I set canonical for homepage in magento 2?

Comment: you have to enable mod rewrite .https://blog.mdnsolutions.com/magento-2-remove-index-php-from-urls/

Comment: Instead of using htaccess, How can I set homepage canonical?

Comment: can you share live URL ?

Comment: Please share your website URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good way to add rule in .htaccess for index.php, but if you want to add canonical its also quite simple just edit home page (content->pages->home)and update layout for home page as mentioned in the following image:-

[image]

```
<head>
      <link rel="canonical" src="https://www.hayacreations.com/" src_type="url"/>
</head>
```

resulting output will be:

[image]